# Why would my new WordPress site require a 301 redirect?

Tags: seo, htaccess, wordpress, 301-redirect

I just finished moving a site from localhost to its final domain, and the thing is that the SEO guys is saying I need to make a "301 redirect" from the old site to the new one, but there is no such thing, since the new site replaced the old site and the old site is now on a subfolder with a `Disallow` statement in robots.txt.

So any idea what the SEO guy means? He says this needs to be done so all the SEO is not lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all the URLs on the new site identical to what they were on the old site? If yes, you don't need to do anything. If no, you'll want to setup 301 redirects for any old URLs which have a new equivalent.